# Change geometry of QRegion

Tags: c++, qt, qregion

I implemented autohide feature using QRegion and mouseMove event. Now I have another problem. I need to change geometry of QRegion during runtime but I can't find any suitable command. Can you help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign it another QRegion. Example:

```
QRegion myRegion(/* ... */);

// Change myRegion
myRegion = QRegion(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Thank you, simple solution.